# How to set and retrieve a void* in swift from objective-c methods?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using swift and objective-c together, but I can't figure out how to set and retrieve an Int in swift to a void*. The void* pointer is stored in c++. This is an objective-c wrapper for c++ library.

Objective-C methods

```
-(void) setUserData:(void*) data{
    self.body->SetUserData(data);
}
-(void*) getUserData{
    return self.body->GetUserData();
}
```

In swift I would like to pass an Int to setUserData and retrieve it as an Int from getUserData. Could be other datatypes as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about `setUserData:`. You will need to create an UnsafeMutablePointer specified to the desired type, populate it, and pass it. For example, in theory you could say:

```
    let number = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
    number.memory = 42
    thing.setUserData(number)
```

But I'm not sure you can *really* say that; it all depends on how the code at the far end is going to treat this value. Passing a Swift struct (which is what an Int is) might make no sense here. Personally, I'd wrap it in an NSNumber just to be on the safe side. But then there might also be memory management issues; you are just passing a pointer, so passing a pointer to a local (as in the above code) could be disastrous.